# Can i post twitter cards on users timeline

Tags: android, ios, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I am creating a mobile APP in which a user takes a Photo from its Android/iPhone and posts it on twitter and the post is done using a Gallery Card and Photo Card. I have registered at `https://dev.twitter.com` and it is giving me some instructions on integrating on my website with it, but I just want to know if we can post this on a user timeline or not.

I have submitted my Web Page for approval from

```
[https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/validation/validator][1]
```

Kindly guide me on resolving this.

Thanks.